# Weird Context Behaviour in LWC and Apex

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, navigation, toast

I'm writing a simple 'Merge Lead and Opp' lwc that leverages apex to transfer some custom fields from the lead to the opp before deleting the lead. The apex works fine.

The issue is that when the apex promise resolves, I try to dispatch a toast and then navigate to the lead record list view. It's the last part that causes issues. Sometimes (and I mean sometimes - I haven't been able to isolate a constituent culprit) the toast isn't shown and the the navigation doesn't work either. If one doesn't work, at least none of them work...

My code:

lwc

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

import mergeLeadAndOpp from '@salesforce/apex/RelatedActivities.mergeLeadAndOpp';


// Contains an object with button and action for their respective object
const CUSTOM_ACTIONS = {
    Lead: {
        button: {
            type: "button", initialWidth: 100,
            typeAttributes: {
                label: 'Merge', variant: 'brand', name: 'lead_opp_merge',
                
                // This is the function that gets called. This always works.
                onclick: (_this, selectedRecordId) => {
                    if (window.confirm('Sure you want to merge lead and opp?')) {
                        _this.isLoading = true;


                        // NOTE - dispatching a 'test toast event' here always gets shown on screen,
                        // also when the real toast in the promise resolve doesn't.

                        mergeLeadAndOpp({ leadId: _this.record.Id.value, oppId: selectedRecordId })
                            .then(() => {

                                // always gets called. 'merged' is always in the log.
                                const evt = new ShowToastEvent({ title: '_successTitle', message: '_successBody', variant: 'success' });
                                _this.dispatchEvent(evt);
                                console.log('merged');


                                _this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                                    type: 'standard__objectPage',
                                    attributes: { objectApiName: 'Lead', actionName: 'list' }
                                });
                            })
                            .catch(err => { console.log('err merging', err); })
                            .finally(() => { console.log('finally'); _this.isLoading = false; })
                    }

                }
            }
        },
    },
}



export default class RelatedActivitiesPopover extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @track isLoading;

    onclick(event) {
        const row = event.detail.row;
        event.detail.action.onclick(this, row.Id);
    }
}
```

Apex code (works fine):

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void mergeLeadAndOpp(Id leadId, Id oppId) {
   try {
       Lead lead = [SELECT custom_field__c, OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leadId WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];
       Opportunity opp = [SELECT custom_field__c, OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];

       opp.custom_field__c = lead.custom_field__c;
       opp.OwnerId = lead.OwnerId;
       update opp;

       delete lead;
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.debug('Error -> ' + e.getMessage());
       throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

When I remove the 'delete lead' part of the apex code, the navigate and toast gets consistent (?).

I originally thought I had messed up with the context of the 'onclick' function, but (I think) passing the context to the onclick function as a parameter should mitigate that?

Sometimes the apex promise resolves and the toast/navigation works and sometimes it doesn't, seemingly randomly (I can't find any one thing that consistently resolves/causes the issue)

Comment: Do you see any kind of error logged? the catch block should log any error that happens on the try block. Also, if you add a breakpoint on the first executable line of the try block - is it always reached (or when you have the error situation it isn't)?

Comment: I haven't checked the developer console vigorously for errors since the lead does get deleted (last line of code in the apex function) and the logs in the 'then' part of the promise in the lwc gets called. (in the code I posted there is one log statement `console.log('merged')`, but I've had many more, and they always get logged)

Comment: I'd try to debug with chrome developer tools, adding a breakpoint on the first executable line of the try block, and another one on the catch block. Try to find out if they're reached in that failure use case - I cannot tell anything else from the code, sorry!

Comment: Yeah same. It's so weird what's going on. Might have to try something entirely new.